# p5.js: change text color in for a single word in a sentence

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I want to change the color of a single word in a string that I am drawing to the canvas, without having to manually fiddle with text locations and have multiple "text()" function calls.

Is this possible in p5?

Example:

```
textAlign(CENTER);
text("I want THIS to be in green.",50,50);
```

Where "THIS" is a different color from the rest of the sentence.

I could use multiple text calls, such as

```
textAlign(CENTER);
fill(255,0,0);
text("I want ",50,50);
fill(0,255,0);
text("THIS",50 + widthOfFirstPart,50)
fill(255,0,0);
text("to be in green.",50 + widthOfSecondPart,50);
```

But that seems clunky, UNLESS there is a good way to solve for the "widthOfFirstPart" and "widthOfSecondPart" variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to create a function, which handles an array of tuples, consisting of text and color.

e.g.:

```
var red = [255, 0, 0];
var green = [0, 255, 0];
var string = [
    ["I want ", red],
    ["THIS ", green],
    ["to be in green.", red]
];
```

Process the array in a loop, calculate the length of each text part. Sum the length of the text parts, to determine the start position of each part. Of course the text has to be aligned  `RIGHT` (it would be possible to extend the code, to handle other alignments too):

```
function drawtext( x, y, text_array ) {

    var pos_x = x;
    for ( var i = 0; i < text_array.length; ++ i ) {
        var part = text_array[i];
        var t = part[0];
        var c = part[1];
        var w = textWidth( t );
        fill( c );
        text( t, pos_x, y);
        pos_x += w;
    }
}
```

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas( 500, 200 );
}

function draw() {
    background( 126, 192, 238 );
  
    textAlign(LEFT);
    
    var red = [255, 0, 0];
    var green = [0, 255, 0];
    var string = [
        ["I want ", red],
        ["THIS ", green],
        ["to be in green.", red]
    ];
    drawtext(50, 50, string );
}

function drawtext( x, y, text_array ) {
  
    var pos_x = x;
    for ( var i = 0; i < text_array.length; ++ i ) {
        var part = text_array[i];
        var t = part[0];
        var c = part[1];
        var w = textWidth( t );
        fill( c );
        text( t, pos_x, y);
        pos_x += w;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Using this as an example, I was able to create a function to italicize specific words in a string.